# What is the maximum value of n such that the number $n!$ can be represented as a product of $(n−3)$ consecutive positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving, factorial

What is the maximum value of n such that the number $n!$ can be represented as a product of $(n−3)$ consecutive positive integers?

Im not sure how to solve this, hints and solutions would be appreciated

Taken from the 2013 AITMO

Comment: Think about how big the largest of those $n-3$ integers can (or must) be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a solution of $$n!=\frac{(n+a-3)!}{a!}.$$
For successive values of $a$ this means we need to solve:
$$n+1=4!$$
$$(n+1)(n+2)=5!$$
$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=6!$$
$$...$$
Now the first of these equations gives us a solution with $a=4 \text{ and }n=23$. We therefore only need solutions with $n\ge 23$. However, for $n\ge 23$, the LHS of successive equations is multiplied successively by at least $25,26,27,...$ whilst the RHS is multiplied successively by $5,6,7,...$ so there are no such solutions.

The solution is $n=23$, when$$23!=5\times 6\times 7 ... \times 24.$$

Comment: But I do not see how this solution is included in the answer.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: It was not included because "We therefore only need solutions with n≥23. However, for n≥23, the LHS of successive equations is multiplied successively by at least 25,26,27,... whilst the RHS is multiplied successively by 5,6,7,... so there are no such solutions."

Comment: Oh now I see, they did not need the complete solution set.

Comment: Yes - its a much easier question than many posted by this OP.